# SpriteKit animation error

Tags: ios, animation, sprite-kit

I want to make the hero to animation when he jumps

```
 NSArray *animatedImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"hero_1.png"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"hero_2.png"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"hero_1.png"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"hero_.png"], nil];
    SKAction *jump = [SKAction animateWithTextures:animatedImages timePerFrame:0.2];
    [hero runAction:jump];
```

This code is placed in `didBeginContact`

The error

```
-[UIImage isRotated]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage isRotated]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1780945a0'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't animate UIImage objects, they have to be SKTexture objects.

```
NSArray *animatedImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"hero_1.png"],
                               [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"hero_2.png"],
                               [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"hero_1.png"],
                               [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"hero_.png"], nil];
```